# How to change AzureADOptions at runtime

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory

I am trying to change AzureADOptis at run time. I tried the following, but after this, clicking on the sign in link takes old values for redirecting it to microsoft login page. Expectation is to take updated options.

```
var options = new AzureADOptions
            {
                Instance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
                Domain = "....",
                TenantId = "....",
                ClientId = "....",
                CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc"
            };

            _optionsCache.TryRemove(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            _optionsCache.TryAdd(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OpenIdConnectOptions` since `AzureADOptions` will also map to `OpenIdConnectOptions` in library  . And you need to inject  `OpenIdConnectPostConfigureOptions` into DI system and call `_postConfigureOptions.PostConfigure` before `_optionsCache.TryAdd` :

`ConfigureServices.cs`:

```
services.AddSingleton<OpenIdConnectPostConfigureOptions>();
```

In your Controller:

```
private readonly IAuthenticationSchemeProvider _schemeProvider;
private readonly IOptionsMonitorCache<OpenIdConnectOptions> _optionsCache;
private readonly OpenIdConnectPostConfigureOptions _postConfigureOptions;

public HomeController(IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemeProvider, IOptionsMonitorCache<OpenIdConnectOptions> optionsCache, OpenIdConnectPostConfigureOptions postConfigureOptions)
{

    _schemeProvider = schemeProvider;
    _optionsCache = optionsCache;
    _postConfigureOptions = postConfigureOptions;
}
```

In your action :

```
var OIDCoptions = new OpenIdConnectOptions
{                             
    Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenantID/",              
    ClientId = "YourClientID",
    CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc"
};            
_postConfigureOptions.PostConfigure(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, OIDCoptions);
_optionsCache.TryRemove(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme);
_optionsCache.TryAdd(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, OIDCoptions);
```