# Asp.Net Core - modify authentication schemes while server is running

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication

Is there a way to modify/add/remove authentication schemes while the server is running?

I need to add scheme **without** restarting my server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key for adding new scheme resides withing the `IOptionsFactory<TOptions>` object.

While you may configure multiple `IAuthenticationHandler`'s of same type the `authenticationScheme` fields specifies each's configuration (in source code it is referred as `TOptions`).

As all runtime options are configured and "sealed" at startup (see: [options in asp.net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options)). It is not possible to add new option at runtime (at least without writing some code).

To add new authentication scheme we need to:

1. Add new `ConfigureNamedOptions<TOptions>` to the `IOptionsFactory<TOptions>`. This provides the configuration to the scheme's `IAuthenticationHandler` when it is initialized
2. Add new scheme to `IAuthenticationSchemeProvider`. This binds an instance of `AuthenticationHandler` to the specific authorization scheme options provided in step 1
3. Clear `IOptionsMonitorCache<TOptions>` cache - Forces options refresh

This code adds `OpenIdConnectHandler`

```
//adds oidc2 scheme
var toAdd = new AuthenticationScheme("oidc2", "oidc2- display", typeof(OpenIdConnectHandler));
if (!_authenticationSchemeProvider.TryAddScheme(toAdd))
    return false;
var a = new Action<OpenIdConnectOptions>(options =>
{
    //configuration goes here
    options.Authority = "https://demo.identityserver.io/";
    options.ClientId = "c-id2";
});
_factory.AddOption("oidc2", a);
//clear cache
var allSchemes = await _authenticationSchemeProvider.GetAllSchemesAsync();
var services = Request.HttpContext.RequestServices;
var c = services.GetService<IOptionsMonitorCache<OpenIdConnectOptions>>();
foreach (var s in allSchemes)
    c.TryRemove(s.Name);
```

[Click here to see source code on github](https://github.com/saturn72/aspnetcore-crud-authentication-scheme)

before adding `oidc2` scheme: `oidc1` can access the identity server while `oidc2` cannot
[image]

[image]

After adding `oidc2` scheme programmatically - `oidc2` can access identity provider
[image]

Answer (score -1):

**If you want change the code which is running in your server, it's impossible to modify `authentication schemes`.**

*Unless you use Azure webapp, you can create a slot to hot start your application.*

## Suggestion:

You need change your code, and rebuild your project, and you must retsart your webapp. You can think about how to add authentication schemes dynamically.

[AuthSamples.DynamicSchemes](https://github.com/aspnet/AuthSamples/tree/master/samples/DynamicSchemes)

This repo should be useful to you. For more details, you can refer below post.

[Adding new authentication schemes dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910070/adding-new-authentication-schemes-dynamically/49825151#49825151)

Comment: Or you also can use [`services.AddSingleton<OpenIdConnectPostConfigureOptions>();`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60548547/how-to-change-azureadoptions-at-runtime/60558508#60558508) .

Comment: your suggestion is for loading and not runtime modification